Java Program - Auto Printer/ Hot Folder
I have been working on developing Java code. There is many functions/methods. I uses JFrame and has buttons that do different things. One of the buttons allows you to set a directory path on which you want to work from. I created another button and called it Activate. My goal for this would be to check the directory path and see if there are any files, If yes print them out, if not go to wait status? I was thinking this might be achieved with a while loop. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you
public static void FilesExist() {
    
    File dir = new File(theSelectedPath);
    Path directoryToWatch = Paths.get(theSelectedPath);
            
    String[] flist = dir.list();
    int flag = 0;
    if (flist == null) {
        System.out.println("The Directory is Empty.");
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < flist.length;i++) {
            File f = new File(theSelectedPath);
            String filename = flist[i];

            if(f.isDirectory()) {
                
                
                 if (filename.toString().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                 System.out.println("File has been found : " + filename);
                                     //This does print out the .pdf files in the directory                   
                 }
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(filename + "found");
            }
        }         
    }       
}


Most of your prose seems irrelevant and distracting. When posting here, pare down your writing to focus narrowly on one specific technical issue.

You may want to describe the "wait status" more precisely. What should it wait for? And for how long?

"I have been working on developing Java code" - kind of obvious since posting a Java code and using the [tag:java] tag; "There is many functions/methods." - is that your problem? Most often that is not a problem; "I uses JFrame and has buttons that do different things" - yet not the problem, is it? --- "Hot Folder" suggests you want something like Path.register() to be informed when the directory is changed (entry created)

Sorry about that, what I am trying to accomplish Is a hot folder in java. I would like to be able to drop a pdf file into a folder and have it physically printed.

A more suitable duplicate uses WatchService
